# Timeout issue with python google cloud storage libraries when using Python Multithreading

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, python-multithreading

The problem that I'm trying to solve is to unzip a bunch of zip files sitting in the GCS bucket. As part of processing these files, I update the file status accordingly in a MongoDB using API endpoints. I have a method that takes a dictionary as an argument and do the following.

1. Update the status of the file to PROCESSING
2. Download the file from the GCS bucket.
3. Unzip the file.
4. Upload the unzipped file back to the GCS bucket.
5. Update the file status as FINISHED

As I have multiple files sitting in the bucket to unzip tried using python multithreading to parallelize the operation to process each zip file in a separate thread, but after a minute or so getting the `requests.exceptions.Timeout` error thrown by google libraries.

When I try processing the files without using multithreading then it works fine without any error. Below are the code and stack trace for reference. Any help is much appreciated.

```
def process_files_multithreading(self, file_info):
    print("process id: " +str(os.getpid()))
    try:
        print("Updating the file status to PROCESSING")
        update_file_status_url = utils.getUpdateFileStatusUrl(config["host"],
                                                                        file_info["fileId"])
        utils.updateFileStatus(update_file_status_url,"PROCESSING")
        client = gcs_utils._getGCSConnection()
        blob_path = file_info["fileLocation"]
        bucket = client.get_bucket(file_info["bucketName"])
        blob = bucket.blob(blob_path)
        zipbytes = io.BytesIO(blob.download_as_string())

        if is_zipfile(zipbytes):
            with ZipFile(zipbytes, 'r') as myzip:
                print(myzip.namelist())
                for contentfilename in myzip.namelist():
                    contentfile = myzip.read(contentfilename)
                    blob = bucket.blob(blob_path + "/" + contentfilename)
                    blob.upload_from_string(contentfile)
            print("proccessed file {} successfully".format(blob_path))
            print("updating the file status to FINISHED")
            update_file_status_url = utils.getUpdateFileStatusUrl(config["host"], file_info["fileId"])
            utils.updateFileStatus(update_file_status_url,"FINISHED")
    except(Exception):
        print("Exception in processing the file")
        print("updating the file status to FAILED")
        update_file_status_url = utils.getUpdateFileStatusUrl(config["host"], file_info["fileId"])
        utils.updateFileStatus(update_file_status_url,"FAILED")
        print(traceback.format_exc())

'''
calling the above function using ThreadPoolExecutor
'''

# files is the list of dictionaries

with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(files)) as pool:
    pool.map(self.process_files_multithreading, files)
```

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
    blob.upload_from_string(contentfile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1361, in upload_from_string
    predefined_acl=predefined_acl,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1261, in upload_from_file
    client, file_obj, content_type, size, num_retries, predefined_acl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1171, in _do_upload
    client, stream, content_type, size, num_retries, predefined_acl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1118, in _do_resumable_upload
    response = upload.transmit_next_chunk(transport)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 425, in transmit_next_chunk
    retry_strategy=self._retry_strategy,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/_helpers.py", line 136, in http_request
    return _helpers.wait_and_retry(func, RequestsMixin._get_status_code, retry_strategy)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py", line 150, in wait_and_retry
    response = func()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 287, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 110, in __exit__
    raise self._timeout_error_type()
requests.exceptions.Timeout
```

Comment: where is this code running? and how are you doing the thread management?

Comment: @JoséSoní - Running this code on my local which has connectivity to goole storage and other components to update the status. Thread management is happening via the context manager using ThreadPoolExecutor. 
Also, when I try to run the code without threads (process one file at a time) it is working as expected, but when I change this to run in parallel using threads getting the exception.

Comment: Could you try running this from a VM on Google Cloud Platform,  Using your code I am not getting the timeout you mentioned. so it seems to be a network issue possibly